# The end of the Universe

Tags: cosmology, universe

I was reading about antimatter and dark energy and how Hawking Radiation can destroy black holes when I came across three theories about how the universe might end.

There are various theories regarding the end of the universe, like the Big Rip, the Big Freeze, and the Big Crunch. The first two reasons that Dark Energy is stronger than the gravitational force between objects and the last one reasons that gravitational attraction is, in fact, the stronger one.
The Big Freeze says the universe will experience a heat death where the endless expansion of the universe will cause the objects to get farther and farther away till the stars lose all fuel for nuclear reactions and die out, and the only things remaining are the black holes. The Big Rip is a little bit similar, stating that all objects from stars and galaxies to atoms and subatomic particles, and even spacetime itself, is progressively torn apart by the expansion of the universe until distances between particles will become infinite and the universe as we know it ceases to exist. The Big Crunch on the other hand states that since gravity is stronger than the force exerted by the dark energy the expansion of the universe eventually reverses and the universe recollapses, till the last of atoms and subatomic particles fuse, ultimately causing the cosmic scale factor to reach zero, an event potentially followed by a reformation of the universe starting with another Big Bang. Is my understanding of these three theories correct? Please elaborate and explain these if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on current accumulated astronomical evidence, the Big Freeze is closest to what I understand that most cosmologists accept as most likely. There is a slight detail you left out, which is the black holes will eventually convert all of their mass into particles as a result of Hawking radiation. Also, since gravity keeps the mass of a galaxy (and also some galaxy groups) these collections will remain regular mass stuff until all of the energy of orbital motion is dissipated and the galactic component objects will eventually become black holes. and then much much later become the particles from Hawking radiation.

The Big Crunch is almost certain not to happen. It would only happen if some currently unknown physics would cause the dark energy to cease to exits.

The Big Rip requires that the expansion will have a expansion rate value such that it can pull apart the mass inside a black hole. Imagine a very large black hole. At its event horizon the escape velocity is c. The effect of expansion causes separation motion between a reference origin and the corresponding radius of the observable universe
to be c. In order for the expansion to pull apart a black hole, the event horizon must be smaller than the radius of the black hole. I have never seen any cosmological calculation that says this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

When considering issues of this kind, you need to distinguish between a scientific model and the physical reality. When people say this or that is "what will happen" what they are really saying is "under the assumption of model X, this is what will happen" where model X is some sort of reasonable combination of what we know about gravity, black holes, entropy and the like. But when grappling with the long-term future of the cosmos as a whole, we have to remember that we have only got models based on what we have learned so far. All such models ought to be taken with a pinch of salt. More formally, they should only be extrapolated while keeping in view some awareness of the limited precision and depth of all scientific enquiry. So whereas one model may say "big rip" and another "big freeze" or another "big crunch", what may happen in the physical reality is "none of the above". The most appropriate scientific summary statement is "we do not know what will happen on that scale of time and density."